# Attempting to send email with pdf attachment failing, ends up sending broken attachment

Tags: node.js, typescript, email, base64, sendgrid

I'm trying to send attachments loaded from a remote URL but they're always ending up broken (no data in the attachment, just blank pages).

This is the code I'm using to get the data from the URL and then send it. The testpdf endpoint does work and returns a valid pdf file (have also tried linking to images and other types of files but they all end up not sending correctly).

```
        const pdfData = await fetch(url);
        
        await SendEmail({
            from: 'help@example.com',
            to: email,
            html: '<html>text attachment</html>',
            subject: 'Attachment test',
            attachments: [{
                content: Buffer.from(await pdfData.text(), 'base64').toString(),
                filename: 'program.pdf',
                type: 'application/pdf'
            }]
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in what format `fetch(url)` returns your pdf. Currently you are treating the result as a base64 encoded string (which IMHO is rather unlikely). Ie `Buffer.from(foobar, 'base64')` treats the content of `foobar` as base64 string and parses it to a binary buffer.

Then on this binary buffer you are calling `toString()` which is definitively wrong, because that won't create a base64 string like [sendgrid API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send) expects it.

So depending on what is really returned from `fetch(url)` you can do the following

- If it returns a base64 string, you can just pass that on to your sendgrid api call

  ```
  let pdfResult = await fetch(url);
  let base64 = await pdfResult.text();
  ```
- If it returns binary data, you can use as follows

  ```
  let pdfResult = await fetch(url);
  let base64 = Buffer.from(await pdfResult.arrayBuffer()).toString('base64');
  ```

In any case, before accessing the response body, you should probably also check, if you got a success response code, ie

```
let pdfResult = await fetch(url);
if (!pdfResult.ok) {
  //do some error handling here ... 
}
let base64 = ...
```

And then you can use

```
await SendEmail({
   ...
   attachments[{
     content: base64, 
     ...
   }]
});
```